# How to access Wordpress through Static VPS IP

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

Just spun up an AWS Lightsail VPS and have WP Installed.
Created a Public Static IP and changed wp-config.php siteURL and Home to match.

```
http://ip/
```

I am now trying to access the Admin login using http://ip/wp-admin.php and all it shows is the original plesk default website installation page.

Even with rebooting the VPS, not sure what else I can do to access using the Static IP.

Comment: Can you clarify how you setup the instance? Did you base it on the Plesk blueprint or the WordPress one?

Comment: Random question: If you used the Plesk blueprint, why did you choose that over just using the WordPress one?

Comment: Hey Mike - I chose the Plesk Blueprint. I chose that over WP as I wanted to test out hosting 3 WP on the instance vs having to setup 3 different WP instances. More for efficiency than anything else.

Comment: There is a blueprint on lightsail for Multi-site wordpress - if your goal is multiple WP sites on one server, that might be a more direct route. Also, see my answer below I'm fairly confident that's why you're seeing the default page (the process below sets the default page to the WP site).

Answer (score 0):

Ok - this worked for me on a Plesk Lightsail instance with the default WordPress install

Login to the plesk interface (http://ip:8443)

Click on 'tools and settings' on the left hand side of the screen

Click on IP Addresses from the list of settings (it's under tools & resources)

Click on the IP address of your server

Under default site, select your wordpress site

If you still get the default site, try another browser or an incognito window (I kept getting the cached site and thought it was still broke)

Comment: Mike - You're somewhat right.
1. I've gone ahead and done that, and the site shows. Question: What happens however if there's a 2nd, a 3rd domain added. All staging environments that need to access individual WP-admin's using Server IP?
2. Upon testing the http://ip/wp-admin, the domain still redirects to http://domain/wp-admin which isn't what I would like. I'd like the IP to remain persistent until testing on the new WP is done. Any ideas Mike?

Answer (score 0):

Is the wordpress setup as a virtual host?

If so, then you have to use the server name you configured in the web server in order to access it.

If you access via IP, it will go to the default host on the server.

Comment: Hey David - as of now, Im pretty sure I did not setup as a virtual host. Didn't see a section where I can do that?? By going to the server IP, it goes to the default host page, rather than the WP site itself, even with the wp-options.php siteURL and Home set to the IP. In theory, would every site require a virtual host? I wanted to host 3 WP sites on this single Plesk Instance.

Comment: I don't know anything about Plesk ... I manage my servers manually. Since lightsail instances can only have a single external IP, each separate domain you are hosting would require a virtual host configured.  I'm currently running about 10 web sites on my lightsail instance. Each has it's own virtual host.